# Black laptop screen on a running laptop

Tags: laptop, drivers, display, graphics-card, graphics

Warm greetings!
I am experiencing black laptop screen while it is still on (ASUS X510UA, Windows 10- home, graphic driver, Intel (R) HD Graphics 620:  version 27.20.100.8477).
It means a world to me if anyone can help me solve this issue:
A) I can have--mostly, not always--access to the screen (without hard reset dozens of times) only if I directly connect the laptop to a 2nd screen via HDMI port.
B) Only when I uninstall the graphic driver in Safe Mode, my laptop screen works once (not after "Hibernate"/ "Shut Down") . Thus, if I could get it back to normal (by following 1-8 methods), it will reverse to black screen again after "Hibernate"/ "Shut Down" (screen works after "Restart" or when I use "Hibernate"/ "Shut Down" and turn it on again within 5-7 minutes,).
C) I ran the RAM test (RUN--> mdsched.exe), and everything was ok. My guess, graphic driver problem.
**** What I did so far:

1. Shortcut keys: Windows logo key + P or Ctrl + Alt + Del./ Windows logo key + Ctrl + Shift + B. (rarely work)
2. Hard reset many times (not only via power button but also disconnecting the battery by opening the laptop).
3. Startup Setting--> Enable Low-Resolution Video Mode==> Uninstalled Graphic Driver
4. Re-installed my Windows three times!
5. Startup Setting--> Reset BIOS
6. Startup Setting-->Deleting the updates--> It only solved the white-halo-around-screen problem
7. Startup Setting-->Safe Mode ==> Uninstalled "Graphic Driver" and "Monitors" But every time I hibernate/ shut it down, the same story of black screen begins. In the Device Manager, the Graphic driver always reads as "UPDATED". I downloaded the graphic driver from https://www.asus.com/support/download-center, and installed it all in vain.
8. Startup repair couldn't repair your PC. Windows Repair log:
   Startup Repair diagnosis and repair log --------------------------- Last successful boot time: ‎1/‎17/‎2024 Number of repair attempts: 1 Session details --------------------------- System Disk = \Device\Harddisk1 Windows directory = E:\WINDOWS AutoChk Run = 0 Number of root causes = 1 Test Performed: --------------------------- Name: Check for updates Result: Completed successfully. Error code = 0x0 Time taken = 0 ms Test Performed: --------------------------- Name: System disk test Result: Completed successfully. Error code = 0x0 Time taken = 0 ms Test Performed: --------------------------- Name: Disk failure diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code = 0x0 Time taken = 16 ms Test Performed: --------------------------- Name: Disk metadata test Result: Completed successfully. Error code = 0x0 Time taken = 125 ms Test Performed: --------------------------- Name: Disk metadata test Result: Completed successfully. Error code = 0x0 Time taken = 0 ms Test Performed: --------------------------- Name: Target OS test Result: Completed successfully. Error code = 0x0 Time taken = 15 ms Test Performed: --------------------------- Name: Volume content check Result: Completed successfully. Error code = 0x0 Time taken = 47 ms Test Performed: --------------------------- Name: Boot manager diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code = 0x0 Time taken = 0 ms Test Performed: --------------------------- Name: System boot log diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code = 0x0 Time taken = 0 ms Test Performed: --------------------------- Name: Event log diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code = 0x0 Time taken = 16 ms Test Performed: --------------------------- Name: Internal state check Result: Completed successfully. Error code = 0x0 Time taken = 0 ms Test Performed: --------------------------- Name: Check for installed LCU Result: Completed successfully. Error code = 0x0 Time taken = 3500 ms Test Performed: --------------------------- Name: Check for installed driver updates Result: Completed successfully. Error code = 0x0 Time taken = 1312 ms Test Performed: --------------------------- Name: Check for pending package install Result: Completed successfully. Error code = 0x0 Time taken = 2391 ms Test Performed: --------------------------- Name: Boot status test Result: Completed successfully. Error code = 0x0 Time taken = 0 ms Root cause found: --------------------------- Boot status indicates that the OS booted successfully.

Comment: Try to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: Once short Sleep past, the PC wake eternally?